# Excel VBA: Search for a directory

Tags: vba, excel

In vba, I would like to search through directories for a specific directory name. Ideally the searching time would be fast (similar from a windows search).

from different sources, I could build a script (given bellow) with a recursive sub program. The script works but it is very slow as soon as the hierarchy is a little complex.

Is there a way to make the search faster?

```
Sub GetFolder(Folder As String, searchF As String, colFolder As Collection)
Dim SubFolder, subF As New Collection, sf As String
If Right(Folder, 1) <> "\" Then Folder = Folder & "\"

If Dir(Folder & searchF, vbDirectory) <> "" Then colFolder.Add Folder & searchF & "\"

sf = Dir(Folder, vbDirectory)
Do While Len(sf) > 0
    If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then
        If (GetAttr(Folder & sf) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                subF.Add Folder & sf
        End If
    End If
    sf = Dir()
Loop

For Each SubFolder In subF
    GetFolder CStr(SubFolder), searchF, colFolder
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Read what Norie said [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/449193-vba-fastest-most-reliable-way-list-files.html). `You could write a small batch file that sends all the filenames, and other information, to a text file using a pipe.

When I say small I mean small - it would probably be one line of code.

The text file generated could then be easily opened in Excel.` or the code written there.

Comment: @danieltakeshi the problem would then be that I would have to then create temporary files and all issues that comes with them, or do you know a way to simply deal with temporary files in vba?

Comment: Well, I don't know. What i would do is to get a database list of all directories everytime the Search Workbook is open, then you could make as many searches as possible inside Excel.

Comment: @danieltakeshi that is a very good idea, it does not really adapt to my case because the folder are dynamic and can update, but I will keep this idea in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are underestimating the hierarchy size. Change your code to this one to see how many folders you are recursing through.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFolder(Folder As String, searchF As String, colFolder As Collection, ByRef counter As Long)

    Dim SubFolder, subF As New Collection, sf As String
    If Right(Folder, 1) <> "\" Then Folder = Folder & "\"

    If Dir(Folder & searchF, vbDirectory) <> "" Then colFolder.Add Folder & searchF & "\"

    sf = Dir(Folder, vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(sf) > 0
        If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr(Folder & sf) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print Folder & sf
                counter = counter + 1
                subF.Add Folder & sf
            End If
        End If
        sf = Dir()
    Loop

    For Each SubFolder In subF
        GetFolder CStr(SubFolder), searchF, colFolder, counter
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim newC        As New Collection
    Dim colChecked  As New Collection
    Dim counter     As Long

    GetFolder "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\BA Tools", "v", newC, counter
    Debug.Print counter

End Sub
```

What is the number that you get at the end of the code, when you run it?

Comment: sorry for the slow response: I am recusing through 6637 folders and this takes about 20sec.

Comment: @Jonathan - if you remove the `Debug.Print Folder & sf` it will be faster. Try again :)

Comment: @Jonathan - depending what do you need it for, you can change the logic a bit - you can loop once through all the folders and save the results in a collection. It will take 20 seconds, but the next time you are looking for something you will look into this collection, and not into the folders.

Comment: that is indeed a good idea, unfortunately it does not really adapt to my case because the folder are dynamic and they can get some update, but I will keep this idea in mind. thanks for the pointer!